# Toolbar on custom collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I have created a category in Magento with a custom layout as follows:

```
<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setTemplate"><name>catalog/product/custom.phtml</name></action>
</reference>
```

In this custom.phtml I have modified the $_productCollection in order to get a desired collection to show up, but there is no toolbar generated in order for the results to be sortable or have proper pagination.

Any suggestions on how I can generate the toolbar for the custom collection I just created?

Answer (score 1):

You can add toolbar to your custom collection by adding this to your custom.phtml template

```
$toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton(‘catalog/product_list’)->getToolbarBlock();
$toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);
$toolbar->setChild(‘product_list_toolbar_pager’);
echo $toolbar->toHtml();
```